# Rewrite from subfolder to parent folder

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Site moved from

`http://example.com/dev/` to `http://example.com`

So, everything under `/dev/` needs to redirect to the new URL

`http://example.com/dev/test-page` to `http://example.com/test-page`

I tried this in my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /dev/$1
</IfModule>
```

doesn't seem to work, what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this but shouldn't the rewrite rule be reversed? Now it seems you're rerouting `/*` to `/dev/*`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reverse it, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/dev/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In `.htaccess`, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ cannot start with a slash - it will never match. Also, shouldn't this be a _redirect_, not an _internal rewrite_? So, something like... `RewriteRule ^dev/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]` instead. (?)